# Python migrations custom user model

Tags: python, django, authentication

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction, please? I have built a custom user model as per the below code, however, when I run 'make migrations' it doesn't seem to pick up a few of the fields I have added in the custom user model. I think this is the cause of the following error message whenever I try to create a superuser.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 184, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File ".\HealthcareProject4\Users2\models.py", line 32, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
  File ".\HealthcareProject4\Users2\models.py", line 23, in _create_user
    date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
  File "G:\Shares\Website\Development\Intranet\HealthcareProject4\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 485, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwarg)
TypeError: 'is_staff' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = datetime.datetime.now()  
        
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    area_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True) # a admin user; non super-user
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=True) # a superuser
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
objects = CustomUserManager()


# notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'address1', 'address2', 'area_code', 'country_code'] # Email & Password are required by default.

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return 'users/%s' % urlquote(self.email)

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    full_name = '%s %s' %(self.first_name, self.surname)
    return full_name.strip()

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.first_name

def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
    """
    Sends an email to this User.
    """
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    return self.is_staff

@property
def is_admin(self):
    "Is the user a admin member?"
    return self.is_admin

@property
def is_student(self):
    "is the user a student?"
    return self.student



# Generated by Django 2.1.11 on 2022-03-13 22:26

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('username', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)),
                ('surname', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)),
                ('address1', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=254)),
                ('address2', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=254)),
                ('area_code', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)),
                ('country_code', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10)),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('timestamp', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('confirmed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('confirmed_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Have you also updated the [`AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)?

Comment: Have you inherited the `User` model in your custom user model?

Answer (score 1):

Your model seems fine to me but in manager I see some issues with create methods

Here is what my manager looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_(f'Please enter an email address'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        log.info(f'User created with email: {email}')
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if kwargs.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(f'Superuser must have staff permission')
        if kwargs.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(f'Superuser must have superuser permission')
        log.info(f'Superuser created with email: {email}')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
```

Here goes My custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Group
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """User model saves all the details of a user """
    CUSTOMER = 'CUSTOMER'
    VENDOR = 'VENDOR'
    CMS = 'CMS'
    IMS = 'IMS'

    ROLES = ((CUSTOMER, 'CUSTOMER'), (VENDOR, 'VENDOR'), (CMS, 'CMS'), (IMS, 'IMS'))

    GENDER = (('M', 'MALE'), ('F', 'FEMALE'), ('O', 'OTHER'))

    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True, db_index=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('Phone Number'), max_length=15)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(
        _('Gender'), max_length=10, choices=GENDER, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        _('Profile Image'), blank=True, null=True, upload_to='profile_imgs')
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Created'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Last Updated'), auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLES, default=CUSTOMER)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)


    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User({self.__str__()})>'

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return super().has_perm(perm, obj)

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return super().has_module_perms(app_label)
```

Comment: Thanks- would you mind sharing your custom user model as well?

Comment: @NeilFaulkner You can check out custom user model in answer